# Prove that the splitting field is not an algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Let $n > 0$ be some integer and let $G$ be a splitting field of the set of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ over a field $F$. I need to prove that $G$ is not an algebraic closure of $F$ in the following two cases:

1. $F = \mathbb{Q}$
2. $F = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for prime $p$ (NOT the $p$-adic numbers! I'm talking here about $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the integers modulo $p$.)

However, I have no idea how to get started with either of them. In fact, the idea that $G$ wouldn't be the algebraic closure of $F$ doesn't make much sense to me, since by definition an algebraic closure is an algebraically closed algebraic extension, and in both cases, $G$ seems to be exactly that.

Could someone please explain to me why it makes sense that $G$ would not be the algebraic closure of these fields, as well as some hints on how to show it? Thank you for your time and patience.

---

Please see the comment thread immediately following this question. Some hints have been given to me, but I am having difficulty seeing how to implement them. For example, say I exhibit a polynomial $f$ of degree $p > n$ such that $f$ is irreducible over, say, $F = \mathbb{Q}$. How do I know that $G$ is not a splitting field for $f$ even though $f$ is of greater degree that what $G$ is designed to take care of? Being a splitting field is necessary (although certainly not sufficient) for something to be algebraically closed, right?

Comment: I would try to find a prime $P>n$ and a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ of degree $P$ which is irreducible over $F$.

Comment: @Batominovski is the nuance that I'm missing here that in order for $G$ to be an algebraic closure of a field $F$, it is necessary for EVERY polynomial. **regardless of degree** to split there?

Comment: Yes, all degrees must be accounted for.  However, there are some special cases like the extension $\mathbb{R}<\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is merely the splitting field of all polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $2$, and it is already algebraically closed.

Comment: Hint: Eisenstein's criterion. Also you probably mean $\mathbb Q_p$, not $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @ALannister Well, that's not a field.

Comment: Oh you're not talking about the $p$-adic numbers, are you? This symbol is commonly used to denote them. You probably mean $ \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$. Please add this to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Ravi done. How would Eisenstein's criterion help? I'd need $p^2$ to divide $a_{0}$ in order for the lower order polynomials to be reducible, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Batominovski why does the degree need to be prime?

Comment: @Ravi the problem is, say for $F = \mathbb{Q}$. If I consider a polynomial of degree $p > n$, that is irreducible over $F$, how do I know that $G$ is not a splitting field for that poynomial?

Comment: @ALannister Because degree is multiplicative in towers and you know that $(p,n)=1$.

Comment: @Ravi how do I find an irreducible polynomial of degree $q$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ without using any charactrization of finite fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe $G=F(X)$, where $X$ is the set of all elements of degree $\le n$ in $\overline{F}$ and $F(X)$ is field of all elements expressible as rational expressions in the elements of $X$. This is because these polynomials all split in $F(X)$, and conversely if all these polynomials split in some extension then it contains $F(X)$, thus making it minimal,

Now, suppose $q>n$ is prime. Can $f(x_1,\cdots,x_m)\in F(X)$ have degree $q$ over $F$? Consider the tower of extensions $F(x_1,\cdots,x_m)/\cdots/F(x_1,x_2)/F(x_1)/F$ and think about degrees.

Comment: what does $\overline{F}$ denote?

Comment: Algebraic closure.

Comment: Every element $\alpha$ of $F(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ has degree $[F(\alpha):F]$ which divides $[F(x_1,\cdots,x_m):F]$.

Comment: and since $[F(x_{1},\cdots , x_{m}):F]$ is not divisible by $q$? We know this how?

Comment: @ALannister Look at the tower in my answer. I don't like doing the whole problem for you.

Comment: I looked at the tower! $F \subseteq F(x_{1})  \subseteq F(x_{1},x_{2}) \cdots \subseteq F(x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{m-1})\subseteq F(x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots , x_{m-1}, x_{m})$ which implies that $F(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots , x_{m}):F] = [F(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots , x_{m}):F(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{m-1})]\cdots [F(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}):F(x_{1}x_{2})][F(x_{1},x_{2}):F(x_{1})][F(x_{1}):F]$

Comment: Yes, and all of those factors are $\le n$. So can the product of them be divisible by a prime $q>n$?

Comment: so now I have it for $F = \mathbb{Q}$, but I am having trouble with $F = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ because we have not gotten to the characterization of finite groups yet; that's in the next section.

Comment: I suppose the tower argument holds for this case, too. So all I need to do is find an irreducible polynomial of degree $q$ in $F = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Problem is, I can't rely on any theory on the characterization of finite groups to help me.

Comment: Finite fields, not finite groups. You can take a completely different tact here than for $\Bbb Q$. There are only finitely many polynomials of degree $\le n$ over a finite field $F$, so $G/F$ will wind up having finite degree. Then $G^{\times}$ will be a cyclic group of some finite order, and a generator $\alpha$ will not have an $m$th root for any nontrivial divisor $d$ of  $|G^{\times}|$, so $x^d-\alpha$ cannot split in $G$.

Comment: how do you know $G^{\times}$ is cyclic of finite order? The multiplicative group of a finite field is, but we don't know that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @ALannister I said "There are only finitely many polynomials of degree $\le n$ over a finite field $F$, so $G/F$ will wind up having finite degree" and if $G/F$ has finite degree when $F=\Bbb F_p$ is finite, then $G$ is finite.